# How do I use my Xbox 360 control pad in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3, controllers

Don't get me wrong, mouse and keyboard is, to me, the only way to play the game seriously (multiplayer, usually), however, sometimes I just like to sit back and enjoy myself. Enter: The Xbox 360 controller.

In almost any other modern game, I only need to have the controller plugged in to have it be recognised. Heck, in some of them, I have to remove it just to get access to mouse and keyboard controls. Worst case scenario, the pad control switch is in the options, and you only need to enable it to use a pad.

Mass Effect 3 seems to be missing out on this trend, though.

The controller does not seem to auto-detect or enable and I don't see a switch in the options. I really hope the answer to this is not Xpadder or joy2key, so I ask...

How do I enable the Xbox 360 control pad to work in the PC version of Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mass Effect 3 does not support any other input than mouse and keyboard on the PC, so there is no official way to use an Xbox 360 controller on the PC. See for example [this thread on the official forums where a Bioware employee states that the inability to use a controller is intended](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/344/index/9286247).

Comment: Saying "there is no way" is a bit disingenuous.  Xpadder and joy2key will probably work, as will event ghost.

Comment: I meant no officially supported way, I corrected that ambiguity.

Comment: It's funny how they refuse to support gamepads while simultaneously mangling the control scheme for the benefit of people playing with gamepads.

Comment: This is a bit disappointing to hear. It's not a huge deal, but it's big enough. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Drives me nuts. Mouse gives me RSI, I *have* to use control pad (the controller they designed they game for). Smug "mouse and keyboard is superior" idiots. Thank goodness there are easy fixes out there to counteract the damage done by these PC-master-race morons.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded a GlovePIE script that is working well:

> 1. Download Glovepie - http://www.glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php
> 2. Run GlovePie & Paste the script from - http://pastebin.com/nP4j3c07
> 3. Click Run on Glovepie & Play Simple.
> 4. Adjust Sensitivity in game if needed

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Pinnacle Game Profiler](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/), there's a ME3 profile for PGP [here](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/pc-controller-support/bravo-gamepad-joystick/xbox-madcatz-logitech-saitek-etc-gm/m/mass-effect-3).

Answer (score 1):

No official way, but getting xPadder and Googling "Mass Effect 3 xPadder profile 360" will have you up and running in minutes.